# Sharing JavaVM object between two process in Android

Tags: java, android, process

I want to send the JavaVM object from one process to another process in Android.
Is it possible?

Please suggest me how to do it.

regards
Satyajit

Comment: what java VM object ? there is not such thing in android you got Dalvic and that's your process not an object, so what exactly do you want to send between two processes ?

Comment: If this is referring to the JavaVM struct you get from JNI, then no.  If this just means "how do I send an object from one VM to another", you should look into the Android IPC mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. yes I want to share the JavaVM structure. Can you please explain why it is not possible